# .Net WebService + ExtJs to Fill Grid

Tags: c#, extjs, extjs4.1

I have made a small program to fill gridPanel using ExtJs and .NET webservice method, but it is not filling.. my code is below

//This is my web service method

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
        public List<Student> GetStudentList()
        {
            List<Student> obList = new List<Student>();
            obList.Add(new Student(1, "John", "Doe"));
            obList.Add(new Student(2, "Michael", "Crowd"));
            obList.Add(new Student(3, "Gunnar", "Rasmundsson"));
            obList.Add(new Student(4, "Alicia", "Mankind"));
            return obList;
        }

    public class Student
    {
        private int _stid;
        private string _stname;
        private string _stservice;

        public Student(){}
        public Student(int stid, string stname, string stservice)
        {
            this.StId = stid;
            this.StName = stname;
            this.StService = stservice;
        }

        public int StId {
            get { return this._stid; }
            set { this._stid = value; } 
        }
        public string StName { 
            get{return this._stname;}
            set { this._stname = value; }
        }
        public string StService { get { return this._stservice; } set { this._stservice = value; } }
    }
```

//This is my ExtJs grid fill code

```
        Ext.onReady(function () {
            var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                // Load data at once
                autoLoad: true,
                // Override default http proxy settings
                proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                    // Call web service method using GET syntax
                    url: 'GetStudent.asmx/GetStudentList',
                    // Ask for Json response
                    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
                }),
                // Root variable 
                root: 'd',
                // Record identifier
                id: 'StId',
                //reader:Jreader,
                // Fields declaration
                fields: ['StId', 'StName', 'StService'],
            });


            var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                // Set store
                store: myStore,
                // Columns definition
                columns: [
                    { dataIndex: 'StId', header: 'St Id' },
                    { dataIndex: 'StName', header: 'St Name' },
                    { dataIndex: 'StService', header: 'St Service' }
                ],
                // Render grid to dom element with id set to panel
                renderTo: 'divGrid',
                width: 422,
                height: 300
            });
        });
```

I have also included

```
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                <Services>
                    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/GetStudent.asmx" />
                </Services>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <div id="divGrid"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Please let me know where I am wrong, Thanks for any help !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems fine. Did you check in firefox-firebug? just check the traffic and see what error you are getting.

**EDIT:** adding code.

following is complete working example based on your given example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>ExtJS ASP.NET WebService</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext/ext-all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        Ext.onReady(function () {
            var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                // Load data at once
                autoLoad: true,
                // Override default http proxy settings
                proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                    // Call web service method using GET syntax
                    url: 'Service.asmx/GetStudentList',
                    // Ask for Json response
                    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
                }),
                // Root variable 
                root: 'd',
                // Record identifier
                id: 'StId',
                //reader:Jreader,
                // Fields declaration
                fields: ['StId', 'StName', 'StService'],
            });


            var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                // Set store
                store: myStore,
                // Columns definition
                columns: [
                    { dataIndex: 'StId', header: 'St Id' },
                    { dataIndex: 'StName', header: 'St Name' },
                    { dataIndex: 'StService', header: 'St Service' }
                ],
                // Render grid to dom element with id set to panel
                renderTo: 'divGrid',
                width: 422,
                height: 300
            });
        });                
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divGrid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Service.asmx code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace WebService4ExtJS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [ScriptService]
    public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
        public List<Student> GetStudentList()
        {
            List<Student> obList = new List<Student>();
            obList.Add(new Student(1, "John", "Doe"));
            obList.Add(new Student(2, "Michael", "Crowd"));
            obList.Add(new Student(3, "Gunnar", "Rasmundsson"));
            obList.Add(new Student(4, "Alicia", "Mankind"));
            return obList;
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        private int _stid;
        private string _stname;
        private string _stservice;

        public Student() { }
        public Student(int stid, string stname, string stservice)
        {
            this.StId = stid;
            this.StName = stname;
            this.StService = stservice;
        }

        public int StId
        {
            get { return this._stid; }
            set { this._stid = value; }
        }
        public string StName
        {
            get { return this._stname; }
            set { this._stname = value; }
        }
        public string StService { get { return this._stservice; } set { this._stservice = value; } }
    }
}
```

difference is the  section of html code.

**EDIT:** Adding solution (Provided by Nitin Soni in the comment, adding here so if someone searching should not get confused)

You can see Nitin says in comment the issue is specific to ExtJS version 4.1:

> I checked your code and do the same and yes it works for me too.. I
>   have further analysed that issue is with version of ExtJs. Your code
>   (code project code) is using Extjs 2.2 library files, whereas I have
>   used the Extjs 4.1 latest library files. It seems the issue is with
>   specific ext-all.js file version. I have replaced this file with old
>   version and it works.

Further he provide solution:(again in comment)

> I have found the solution using Extjs 4.1. too, I have to use the
>   following line of code in Store method reader: { type: 'json', root:
>   'd' }

Comment: hi thanks for response, following is my Json response
{"d":[{"__type":"Student","StId":1,"StName":"John","StService":"Doe"},{"__type":"Student","StId":2,"StName":"Michael","StService":"Crowd"},{"__type":"Student","StId":3,"StName":"Gunnar","StService":"Rasmundsson"},{"__type":"Student","StId":4,"StName":"Alicia","StService":"Mankind"}]}

Comment: i found a similar implementation on [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36118/ExtJS-and-NET-Web-Services) probably that would help.

Comment: yes, I have read the same, and implemented the same here, but not getting success.

Comment: Can anyone provide me a small working sample code or link? thanks

Comment: hay, i used your example and it worked for me. in body tag just put <div id="divGrid"></div> (remove Scritmanager etc.)

Comment: Thanks Falaque for the reply. 
I checked your code and do the same and yes it works for me too.. 
I have further analysed that issue is with version of ExtJs. Your code (code project code) is using Extjs 2.2 library files, whereas I have used the Extjs 4.1 latest library files. It seems the issue is with specific ext-all.js file version. 
I have replaced this file with old version and it works. But in my application we have to use latest libraries which seems not supported in this case. Do you have any suggestion regarding this?

Comment: Either I have to switch back to old version or any other way to use latest library. Thanks for any help !!!!

Comment: I have found the solution using Extjs 4.1. too, 
I have to use the following line of code in Store method

                    reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                root: 'd'
                            }

Answer (score 0):

The below is my testing. For my testing purpose I made data directory which is same level to other directories such as app. And I moved Web service file in this directory.
I didn't touch anything in index.html.

And I also added two line of codes for JSON format in WebMethod.

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(obList));
```

For this change, I also changed return type for Student to void in WebMethod.

The below is app.js codes which I made.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',            
        columns: [{
            text: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'StId',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'StName',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Service',
            dataIndex: 'StService',
            flex: 1
        }],
        store: {
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['StId', 'StName', 'StService'],               
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: './data/GetStudent.asmx/GetStudentList',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'd'
                }
            }
        }
    }]
})

});
```

It works for me.